# Embedding for Hilbertian Metric?

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be random variables with densites $X = f_x dx$ and $Y = f_ydx$ with respect to the Lesbegue measure. I'm interested in the metric

$$d(X, Y)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{(f_x - f_y)^2}{f_x+f_y}dx$$

This is called the Le Cam metric, or triangular discrimination (technically they differ by a constant factor). I had a previous question about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846134/triangle-inequality-for-le-cams-metric).

An alternative way to prove that it is a metric is done via [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/850703). I have reproduced the argument below

> By Berg, Christensen,
> and Ressel [4, Ch. 3 (Proposition 3.2)] it suffices to show that the kernel
>  is negative-definite. So let there be given two finite sequences of real
> numbers, $(c_i)$ and $(p_i)$, and assume that $\sum_i c_i = 0$ and that all the $p_i$
> are positive. Then
> $$
> \sum_{i,j}\frac{(p_i-p_j)^2}{p_i+p_j}c_ic_j = -4\sum_{i,j}\frac{p_ip_j}{p_i+p_j}c_ic_j
> =-4\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_i c_i p_i \exp(-tp_i)\right)^2dt\geq 0.
> $$

The citation is to [Harmonic Analysis on Semigroups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1128-0). My understanding is that this implies that there is some map $F : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n\to \mathcal{H}$ into a hilbert space such that

$$d(X,Y) = \lVert F(X) - F(Y)\rVert_\mathcal{H}$$

I can almost see this directly.
In particular, one can write

$$d(X,Y) = \lVert \frac{f_x + f_y}{2} - \frac{1}{(1/f_x) + (1/f_y)} \rVert_2$$

E.g. $d$ is the $\ell_2$-norm of the difference between the arithmetic mean and harmonic mean. But I do not see the existence of the map $F$ that I am interested in yet.

Does such an $F$ have an explicit form?

Comment: The harmonic mean of $a$ and $b$ is $\frac{\color{red}2}{\frac 1a+\frac 1b}$.