# A 2D Inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $\vec p, \vec q \in[0,\infty)^n$, and let $1_n :=\sum_{i = 1}^n e_i =(1,1,\dots,1)$.
Define $L^n : [0,\infty)^n\times [0,\infty)^n\to [0,\infty)$ by
$$
L^n(\vec p, \vec q):=\frac{\langle \vec p - \vec q, 1_n\rangle^2}{\langle \vec p+\vec q, 1_n\rangle},
$$
and
$$
R^n_{\vec p, \vec q}(\vec r) := \sqrt{L^n(\vec p, \vec r)} + \sqrt{L^n(\vec r, \vec q)}.
$$

> **Question:** For $n = 2$ and arbitrary $\vec p, \vec q\in[0,\infty)^n$, is $R^n_{\vec p, \vec q}: [0,\infty)^n\to [0,\infty)$ minimized at $\vec r\in\{\vec p, \vec q\}$?

Note that the answer for $n = 1$ is true.
This is an exercise in calculus, see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846134/triangle-inequality-for-le-cams-metric/4846212#4846212), or [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2078-2489/6/3/361).
Additionally, if one imposes constraints that $\langle \vec p, 1_n\rangle =\langle \vec q, 1_n\rangle = \vec r, 1_n\rangle = \lambda$ for some $\lambda > 0$, it is easy to see that this is true for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The result of $L$ is a couple, consisting of a number and a vector??? Or is it a number, divided by a vector? (How to do that???)

Comment: @Dominique the result is a scalar. I've rewritten to be slightly more general (and hopefully clearer)